# Doubt in Wrapper class

Tags: java

I feel like i got some idea about wrapper classes. My question is when will a method expect object? 
only then we need to use wrapper classes right? 
generally a method expects some paratmeters like
int add(int a); 
Is this "int a" a primitive value?
example pls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object or primitive type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879916/object-or-primitive-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Java primitive types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) are `int`, `double`, `byte`, `boolean`, `char`, `short`, `long`, and `float`.

If a function signature wants `int`, then you are passing it a primitive. If, for example, it wanted `Integer`, it wants the wrapper class `Integer`. In Java 1.5, autoboxing can take effect and automatically wrap primitives into its wrapper type. Unboxing can also take place, where a wrapper class is converted to its primitive equivalent for methods that expect primitives.

```
class Example
{
    public static void usePrimitiveInt(int i) { }
    public static void useIntegerClass(Integer i) { }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int i = 5;
        Integer iObj = 10;
        Example.usePrimitiveInt(i); // use primitive
        Example.useIntegerClass(i); // autobox int to Integer
        Example.usePrimitiveInt(iObj); // unbox iObj into primitive
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you understand wrapper classes. Then there should be nothing to explain. The method expects a wrapper class when the method signature says it does. If the parameter type is `Integer`, the method expects wrapper class. If `int`, it expects primitive value.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that another name for the wrapper pattern is the [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern.
One of the first examples of the wrapper pattern that we see in java are the primitive wrapper classes:

- java.lang.Integer wraps int
- java.lang.Character wraps char
- java.lang.Long wraps long
- etc.

These wrappers are useful when you need object representations of the primitives, for instance when you need to store them in a Collection.
Wrappers can be useful when you need to normalise a common interface across different classes, especially those that you cannot change because for instance they might be part of a 3rd party library.

For example, say you need to process a list of people that will be attending an event, however you may have multiple sources of information with their own representations of a person.

1. Your processing method accepts a list of `Attendee` objects.
2. The first source gives you a list of `Employee` objects
   2.1 The `EmployeeWrapper` contains the `Employee` object and implements or extends `Attendee`
3. The second source gives you a list of Customer objects
   3.1 The `CustomerWrapper` contains the `Customer` object and implements or extends `Attendee`
4. The third list gives you a list of `VendorContact` objects
   4.1 The `VendorWrapper` contains the `VendorContact` object and implements or extends `Attendee`

You now have a normalised representation of the different types of `Attendee` objects.